# ReadProcess Memory 299 on Windows 8

Tags: c++

I have this program that works perfectly in windows 7 but on windows 8 the readprocessmemory seems to be blank when I output it.Get Last error code 299. I Did not create this part of of program for read process but I use it because it was working for windows 7. The game handles and aria location are same on windows 8 machine, I double checked them. and The game handle is found. The address works fine in windows 7.

```
hGameWindow = FindWindow(L"WFElementClient Window",NULL);
if(hGameWindow) {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcId );         
    if( dwProcId != 0 ) {  
        hProcHandle = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcId ); 
        if( hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hProcHandle == NULL ) { 
            GameStatus = "Failed to open process for valid handle"; 
        }else{
            GameStatus = "Game Found";
            myaddr = FindPointerAddr(hProcHandle, ariaBase, aOffset);
            // IsGameAvail = true;
        }
    } 
    else GameStatus = "Failed to obtain process id";
}
else GameStatus = "game handle not found";

ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)myaddr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);

int FindPointerAddr(HANDLE pHandle,int baseaddr, DWORD offsets[])
{
    int Address = baseaddr;
    int offset = 0;
    int offsetCount = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < offsetCount; i++) 
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)Address, &Address , 4, NULL);
        Address+=offsets[i];
    }
    return Address;
}
```

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory` has a return value that tells you if it was successful or not.  If not you can call `GetLastError` to find out why.  Perhaps the error, if there is one, will give you an idea why it isn't working.

Comment: This code looks like it was indented by a sledge-hammer.  Not a great way to ask for help.

Comment: Yeah, find it hard to format code on this site maybe I am missing easy way, will check last error now

Comment: If you [look up the error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 299 is `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed`

Comment: Yes I seen that, but I don't know why it works for windows 7 and not windows 8.

Comment: You should also use the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter to figure out how much you read versus what you asked for.

Comment: Since you have both a working and non-working version, run both versions and step through line by line to see where they diverge. Tell us the divergence point.

Comment: It is not two versions but same code that acts differently right at readprocessmemory. The handle and process ID return correctly. So I think its the readprocessmemory that returns differently. I double checked the addresses and base address for exe is 400000 for both windows 7 and 8. and Aria address should be same which is why I am lost to why it returning 299 error. The variable buffer is unsigned char[150] as I am dealing with very large strings. In windows 7 the correct string shows however in windows 8 it is blank which is shown giving 299 error.

Comment: Right, so step through the code on Windows 7 and write down everything that happens. Then step through the code on Windows 8 and write down everything that happens. Then compare the two runs. At some point, they diverge. That is where you should investigate. The code blindly traverses pointers, so clearly the pointers are different somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Security permissions have changed from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

You may need to run as administrator and set SeDebugPrivelage now, when you were not required to on previous versions of Windows.  Such as when calling OpenProcess() with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS because PROCESS_VM_READ requires SeDebugPrivelage

Here is how you set SeDebugPrivelage:

```cpp
bool SetDebugPrivilege(bool Enable)
{
    HANDLE hToken{ nullptr };
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
        return false;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TokenPrivileges{};
    TokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = Enable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValueA(nullptr, "SeDebugPrivilege", &TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
    }

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &TokenPrivileges, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), nullptr, nullptr))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);

    return true;
}
```